# String replace in C# but only the exact character set

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have the following string:

```
string x = "23;32;323;34;45";
```

and I want to replace 23 with X as below:

```
x = "x:32;323;34;45";
```

but when I try it, I get this instead:

```
x = "x:32;3x;34;45";
```

Is there a way I can get the expecte output?

Comment: Use regex to replace the desired set

Comment: the 23 is ever in the same position? is it always a two digits number?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example for us to work from?

Comment: can you generalize on the input? bring more cases that you might encounter? or is the string always the same and has this structure?

Comment: If you don't want to use a regular expression, then add a semicolon on each side of the original string, then add semicolons to your pattern as well, this will ensure the pattern only matches complete segments, and not parts of segments.

Comment: @MongZhu the string can be anything 23 or 23;34;123;5123;23

Comment: This information belongs into your post

Answer (score 8):

You will need a regular expression (regexp). The replacement rule here is

- word boundary
- 23
- word boundary

so your code would look like this

```
 var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b23\b", "X");
```

An alternative approach would be to split your string, replace matching elements and join to new string>

```
 var result = string.Join(";", input.Split(";").Select(v => v == "23" ? "X" : v));
```

## Update: Update value in Dictionary

Assuming you know the key, that's easy:

```
 myDict["thekey"] = Regex.Replace(myDict["thekey"], @"\b23\b", "X");
```

If you want to do this replacement for all items, I'd do it like this, but I'm not sure, if this is the best possible solution:

```
    [Fact]
    public void Replace_value_in_dict()
    {
        // given
        var mydict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "key1", "donothing" },
            { "key2", "23;32;323;34;45" },
        };

        // when
        var result = mydict
            .Select(kv => (kv.Key, Regex.Replace(kv.Value, @"\b23\b", "X")))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Item1, x => x.Item2);

        // then
        Assert.Equal(result, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "key1", "donothing" },
            { "key2", "X;32;323;34;45" },
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace in a dictionary the string is a dictionary value.Im trying something like this expected[key].Replace("23", "done");

Comment: @Swathy Yes, you can do this on any string. Try it!

Comment: var result = Regex.Replace(expected[(Int64)dataReader["id"]], @"\b"+23+"\b", "X");
                                                expected[(Int64)dataReader["id"]]=result;

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex

```
var x="23;32;323;34;45";
var res = Regex.Replace(x,  @"\b23\b", "x");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Working [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SvCfXi)

Comment: Regex dint work for me since some time the string is just 23 or 23;23;234 . But string split ,replace and join worked .Thanks